# Nifi: formating logs by nifi controller service?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I  have  log  files  which  i make  myself  inside  nifi  environtment  they look like  this:

> "2017-11-28 14:22:32.340 https://linkhere (Get Service)
>   /http://localhost:8080/nifi  getting data  from Service:Successfully
>   received response "

and   i  have   3  type  of  log(  empty response,good  response  and, limitExcedded)
i  want  to convert this  data  into  json  which  will  look like  this  :

```
[ {
  "timestamp" : "2017-11-28 15:06:45,031",
  "level" : "GOODResponse",
  "message" : "https://linkhere (Get Service) /http://localhost:8080/nifigetting data  from Service:Successfully received response" }]
```

1. should   i  use GrokReader +JsonWriter  controller services  or   other  controller  service?
2. Can  i  make  this  by  nifi  processors?
3. Should  i  use  groovy  code  for  this  formating?